# .NetCore C# - Can LINQ Query operators be seperated by logic?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Lets say I have six `LINQ queries`. Each query contains the operators that the previous query used and adds one more operator to the chain:

```
Foo = await
(
    _context.Foo
        .Where(f => (Convert.ToDateTime(f.date1) - today).TotalDays < 31)
 )
 .ToListAsync(); 

Foo = await
(
    _context.Foo
        .Where(f => (Convert.ToDateTime(f.date1) - today).TotalDays < 31)
        .Where(f => f.recordid == x)
 )
 .ToListAsync(); 

Foo = await
(
    _context.Foo
        .Where(f => (Convert.ToDateTime(f.date1) - today).TotalDays < 31)
        .Where(f => f.recordid == x)
        .Where(f => !StatusExceptionList.Contains(r.Status))
 )
 .ToListAsync(); 

Foo = await
(
    _context.Foo
        .Where(f => (Convert.ToDateTime(f.date1) - today).TotalDays < 31)
        .Where(f => f.recordid == x)
        .Where(f => !StatusExceptionList.Contains(r.Status))
        .OrderBy(f => f.date1)
 )
 .ToListAsync(); 

Foo = await
(
    _context.Foo
        .Where(f => (Convert.ToDateTime(f.date1) - today).TotalDays < 31)
        .Where(f => f.recordid == x)
        .Where(f => !StatusExceptionList.Contains(r.Status))
        .OrderBy(f => f.date1)
        .ThenBy(f => f.date2)
)
.ToListAsync(); 

Foo = await
(
    _context.Foo
        .Where(f => (Convert.ToDateTime(f.date1) - today).TotalDays < 31)
        .Where(f => f.recordid == x)
        .Where(f => !StatusExceptionList.Contains(r.Status))
        .OrderBy(f => f.date1)
        .ThenBy(f => f.date2)
        .ThenBy(f => f.recordid)
)
.ToListAsync();
```

I'd like to compact this down to one query, with logic weaved between the different linq operators, as this pseudocode shows, and this doesnt work at all. Ive googled around and not sure what to try next:

```
Foo = await
(
    _context.Foo
        .Where(f => (Convert.ToDateTime(f.date1) - today).TotalDays < 31)
        if (some logic)
        {
            .Where(f => f.recordid == x)
        }
        if (some different logic)
        {           
            .Where(f => !StatusExceptionList.Contains(r.Status))
        }
        if (some different logic)
        {
            .OrderBy(f => f.date1)
        }
        if (some different logic)
        {
            .ThenBy(f => f.date2)
        }
        if (some different logic)
        {
            .ThenBy(f => f.recordid)
        }
)
.ToListAsync();
```

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction or tell me if i'm trying to go about this in the wrong way? Thanks a bunch!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just store query in separate variable:

```
IQueryable<Foo> query = _context.Foo
    .Where(f => (Convert.ToDateTime(f.date1) - today).TotalDays < 31);
```

and then append your checks:

```
if (someCondition) {
    query = query.Where(f.recordid == x);
}
```

and so on. In the end - run query:

```
Foo = await query.ToListAsync();
```

With `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` - check if query is `IOrderedQueryable` already:

```
if (someCondition) {
    var ordered = query as IOrderedQueryable<Foo>;
    if (ordered != null)
        query = ordered.ThenBy(x => x.field);
    else 
        query = query.OrderBy(x => x.field);
}
```

Comment: This was the answer that got me fully understanding what to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can construct the query, and then await its results:

```
IQueryable<Foo> query = _context.Foo
    .Where(f => (Convert.ToDateTime(f.date1) - today).TotalDays < 31);
if (some logic) {
    query = query.Where(f => f.recordid == x);
}
if (some different logic) { 
    query = query.Where(f => !StatusExceptionList.Contains(r.Status));
}
if (some ordering logic 1) {
    query = query.OrderBy(f => f.date1);
}
if (some ordering logic 2) {
    query = ((IOrderedQueryable<Foo>)query).ThenBy(f => f.date2);
}
if (some ordering logic 3) {
    query = ((IOrderedQueryable<Foo>)query).ThenBy(f => f.recordid);
}
```

It is important that "some ordering logic 1" be weaker than "some ordering logic 2" and "some ordering logic 3", otherwise the cast is not going to succeed.

An alternative approach is to make a single `Where` condition:

```
Foo = await
(
    _context.Foo
        .Where(f => (Convert.ToDateTime(f.date1) - today).TotalDays < 31
        && (conditionFor2 && f.recordid == x)
        && (conditionFor3 && !StatusExceptionList.Contains(r.Status))
).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a variable:

```
var query = _context.Foo
    .Where(f => (Convert.ToDateTime(f.date1) - today).TotalDays < 31);

if (something)
{
    query = query.Where(f => !StatusExceptionList.Contains(r.Status));
}
```

and so on.

And in the end:

```
var result = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. I am using await and .ToListAsync() keywords which I believe prevent me from using an anonymous object. Adding the var keyword gives me a message stating 'the name var does not exisit in the current context' and also gives the same message with the .ToListAsync  method.

Comment: @ogg130 You are using var in the wrong scope. Move your logic to separate method like List<Foo> Filter() and start it with the example I gave.

Comment: I see! Thank you, appreciate your patience!